# How to Inspect element of non-inspect able sites?

Tags: css, selector

I want the id or class or CSS selector name of sign-in Gmail button.
I have downloaded the page but can someone tell me how to find the name in these files?

https://auris.ahduni.edu.in/core-emli/code/my_home/

Comment: The relevant class tag for this particular page is `class="abcRioButton abcRioButtonBlue"`, assuming you mean the "Sign in with Google" button, as there doesn't seem to be a gmail sign-in on the page you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome, f12 opens the development console and you can click over to Elements to view the page's HTML with highlighting as chrome normally does with inspect element.